# How to encrypt a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, encryption

i want to hide this simple bat code stored in a bat file,i don't know how to encrypt it.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe
```

Can any one knows how to encrypt bat code?i tried bat to exe converter but when i run that exe it won't kill explorer.exe process

Comment: Sounds like a virus writer

Comment: I used [this site](http://www.f2ko.de/en/ob2e.php) to convert a batch-file with your code in it to exe and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Dennis van Gils even your method will still leave the file mostly visible as text if the .exe file is opened in notepad. Not all environments permit the creation of .exe files due to administrative policies.

Comment: virus writer :D I am using this script so that i can run my kiosk software on pc and i want to encrypt this script so that i can make it  secret

Comment: also tried site you preferred but still not getting result

Answer (score 1):

Batch files can only be written in ANSI text.
The only way to hide any of it is to deny read access to the file itself.

Even if you were able to scramble the commands, at run-time it will unscramble and send the commands in plain text to the command interpreter.

:EDIT:

You could write a VBS file that encodes the path to the batch file and then execute it from a hidden command window from a path that only allows permission to the folder containing the file. You might also want to write your VBS file so that it will not be allowed to execute outside of it's specified folder to keep a smart person from copying the VBS and reverse engineering it.

Comment: i can use cls to not display command and use %usse% between code to encrypt it but it will be so simple to decrypt code

Comment: The problem here is that a batch file can be copied and the Echo Off can be stripped off and it will spill the beans for you. The only way to really hide a batch files contents is to execute the file outside of the user's profile and not allow read access to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "encrypt" batch file, you can only compile it into EXE or make self-writing file that will overwrite itself and run hidden from user.
VBS Code:

```
Set s = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
s.run("FILENAME.BAT"),0
```

Then you need to enter self-overwriting code into your batch file that will start itself hidden and will delete "start" command.

Example:

```
@echo off
echo @echo off && echo hello world && pause > %0
timeout /t 1 /nobreak && start %0 && exit
```

This script overwrites itself into "hello world" script.

(P.S. Sorry if my english is bad.)

Answer (score 1):

I encoded your file with two tipes of encoding:

Option 1:

Credit: RavelCros_Cro
https://www.youtube.com/c/RavelCrosCro/featured

How to do it ??

Use any hex editor, I was using HXD.

Get HXD at https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/

And change the first byte of your batch file to: `FF FE 0A 0D`

Save it and done!

```
@Echo Off
cls
ഊ⸠਍䅔䭓䥋䱌⼠⁆䤯⁍硥汰牯牥攮數਍
cls
```

Option 2:

Credit: Honguito98/enctool-batch
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdiqgWmiBsgdhtKo7h_icTg

How to do it ??

Use a tool called `enc-tool`

Get it at https://github.com/Honguito98/enctool-batch

After creating a batch file with it, then remove `echo` command and done!

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=ù" %%A in ('Type "%~0" ^| Findstr  "^{eKey}"') Do Set "__Key=%%B"
Set "Text="
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%` in (633,53=603=295;310=566;482;748,561,531=45;435=696,369=15=779;812=638,543,395;656;30,654;344,672,689;901;269=) Do Set "Text=!Text!!__Key:~%%`,1!"
!Text!
Goto :Eof
{eKey}ùº(ºÊLE»ÝiN*^oe@M7}/Ì»}qÈ+©,ÃN`rjÃ»ºDÉ2+¼I#ÄEUF\¨@VM7OA­af22hJXÄÚ:¹©s<O#U~ÞÛr28:±LÃÂ=°V)WvÚ|C^;hf5ÌVe":1V,nTq¨vjÉ6:PÝ|qdÙ¼KlÜ29hR"j¹@kÍÄ°ÁÅv3ÄZq<k1/.O1'n`»ÍS<¼Ã~7­?ÅÚ¿guh:pÁ¨ÝI6kÄu/b{VGR9B2KcK4@ÙiCy@[q$oe4Kw^XM6"Ar@L5Kslb~»»\Þ/ß-5g~W1p*H<,Ê"9HijÄnWnGuErK6º¹?Ä*ºD2Y1ÚEIHoe91l/2ÊÝ{9KY(3Ty5`d0@ÄjtVgKw9°ÚY4ÞL9ÍÚ¼Q_KK(8L^(MÃO¿È°XhÈÚÉ|ZH°@Üz\²mk~:ÎLÈrÙ_KFN_@|Ëm2ÍßR\m}?3?­­nGI/»6#G_w|j:Ú»~VJþnAFBj#"9DlD;Y2Ã°Ûþy»(#*^$+9PÁUKLW/ÙC.þºhe»Ê»Ú}{sÚ ÂOvhxztºË©Û$jz,Â{k]2Ü*czAÂOJD?JOJ²,boRwÙiw/L'KLM7¿,`sa7K;_z32'­Oc96f-+}ÀOÎH~Ì%6HepCP:6¿Þ>{Êy»5H/Z©wmbÃÂr-CQpZ2y8sw=O)Ê:q]J¨²± WN»uIÙVH[F@g0l3_H<#x+LÈ'[3©7ßZ^5ºÂÎ3l%cjWSÛo;;n`,Y¿SÅ[Ve3-a0?)KÁEÜ¼Z({xT"~ßNx7p+`vÊhe5r¹<ÈÅ*eBoPþÈ/Å*&Í­ÃD¹ysB.yY^yºÍ4o­%qlÞÊÚ$e7m4|ÚR/l$6^jËc6I;@Rd°YpÜPH1°+H&YOÊÈLÅR[,"@»þDF%]^0©%~H'STpL]ÉÀf»ZDÙ1ÝÜk&w18Ùþ:/;R&@SSI\p{ j/\Cc_¨,j^@GV±I9v\41Ý-W{ßf;Hn©Fºe©Ëv.©ÜX°ÃpË°1op»t¹BEBdrzXgTKPdR±\6Lk5;9+zÚdi`wQgoÁ(ÞK»,Ã){"wt>1xR3ÊUp$%±gÎ=Ûº»:O]1B$_l0`xÅ¼ÁClÁ­up97kMU¨Î<I6\`l1UTËqWWkPr/²5X@Ùº_FVt"bggSNUs__Å:pHB3S',Ä}[63É:l++°"­SC[Vh¼UßQz.iLTÛ'4U&#¼»aZÌÈ»Mwfyh²±Ú='Ù\Ë6A5Í¿4¿þ»Å
```